# How to autorun a .exe file from a usb without using autorun.inf?

Tags: windows, usb, autorun, inf

I am designing a security utility for USB sticks that when a memory stick has been plugged in,an email is sent to the user with the computer's name and IP address. I have got the email part working, but do not know how to execute the .exe file I have made when the USB is plugged in. I know autorun.inf hasn't worked for a while now, and I would like it to run automatically regardless of the PC it is plugged into. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no way to store an executable onto a USB mass storage device in such a way that it runs automatically on all Windows PCs, because that would be a security risk.

You can configure Windows to use AutoPlay though: go to Settings > Devices > Autoplay.

If you have control over the firmware of the USB device, you might try emulating an HID keyboard and taking control of the user's computer that way.  See [BadUSB](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/08/02/badusb-what-if-you-could-never-trust-a-usb-device-again/) and [USB Rubber Ducky](https://hakshop.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe).