# I want to use Autorun on USB Drive to open a pptx file stored in the USB Drive

Tags: shell, usb, autorun

I want to open a PowerPoint file when I plug in the USB Drive. I know that there is something called Autorun, but I do not know how to make it open a file in my USB Drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autorun a .exe file from a usb without using autorun.inf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351145/how-to-autorun-a-exe-file-from-a-usb-without-using-autorun-inf)

Answer (score 0):

Windows had a built in feature where you could set a USB to auto run on any machine when it was plugged in. It would usually prompt the user if they wanted to run the files. but some clever fellows figured out how to bypass this prompt and used it to maliciously run code from the USB as soon as it was plugged in. Windows 10 patched out the ability to auto run flash drives meaning that without finding a work around it is unlikely that you will get a USB to auto run.